# I'm trying to make an union of selects with a while loop, getting errors

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @year int
set @year = 2009

while(year <= 2020)
begin

  SELECT A.dsformfieldvalue                              as Instrumento ,
         AVG(DATEDIFF(day, B.DTSTARTDATE , C.DTENDDATE)) as TempoMedio  ,
         'Jul/2009 a Dez/2009'                           as Periodo
  from       wfflow_form_field_log A
  right join wfflow_execute_task   B on A.codflowexecute = B.codflowexecute
  right join wfflow_execute_task   C on B.codflowexecute = C.codflowexecute
  where A.codflow  in (326, 439)
    and A.codfield =  2498
    and B.codtask  =  7064
    and C.codtask  =  7095
    and CONVERT(CHAR(4), B.DTSTARTDATE, 120) = @year
    and CONVERT(CHAR(4), B.DTSTARTDATE, 100) in ('Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')

  set @year = @year + 1

  group by A.dsformfieldvalue

  union all

end
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is drastically reduce the number of repeated code, as I have to union a whole bunch of selects. I'm trying with a while loop but it is not working. Any input?

Comment: ***WHAT ERROR*** are you getting? We can't read neither your screen, nor your mind ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL is syntactically invalid. The general form of a `select1` statement is

```
select <result-columns>
from <from-clause-including-joins>
where <where-criteria>
group by <group-by-criteria>
having <having-criteria>
order by <order-by-criteria>
```

The general form of `union`/`union all` is

```
<select-statement>
UNION [ALL]
<select-statement>
...
```

where each select statement returns the same number of columns and the corresponding columns in each select statement are of the same type or of a type implicitly convertible to the type of the column in the 1st select statement.

You've placed your statement

```
set @year = @year + 1
```

so that it is a part of the `select` statement.

Further you've added a `UNION ALL` with no `select` statement following.

Fix those problems and you should be good. But...as another answer pointed out, what you're really trying to do is select a range of years. You don't need a `union`: you just need suitable grouping.

If it was my query, I'd do something like this (if I'm understanding your intent correctly):

```
declare @dtFrom datetime = '2009-01-01 00:00:00.000' -- start of period
declare @dtThru datetime = '2020-12-31 23:59:59.996' -- end of period

select year             = datepart(year,b.dtstartdate) ,
       period           = case datepart(month,b.dtstartdate) / 6 when 1 then 'Jan-Jun' else 'Jul-Dec' end ,
       instrumento      = a.dsformfieldvalue ,
       tempomento       = avg( datediff(day, b.dtstartdate , c.dtenddate ) )
from       wfflow_form_field_log a
right join wfflow_execute_task   b on A.codflowexecute = B.codflowexecute
                                  and B.codtask        =  7064
                                  and b.dtStartDate between @dtFrom and @dtThru
right join wfflow_execute_task   d on B.codflowexecute = C.codflowexecute
                                  and C.codtask        =  7095
where A.codflow  in (326, 439)
  and A.codfield =  2498
group by datepart(year,b.dtStartDate) ,
         case datepart(month,b.dtstartdate) / 6 when 1 then 'Jan-Jun' else 'Jul-Dec' end ,
         A.dsformfieldvalue
order by 1,2,3 -- order by the first 3 columns (the grouping columns)
```

Easy!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're trying to do is this

```
select * 
from wfflow_form_field_log A
     right join wfflow_execute_task B on 
          A.codflowexecute = B.codflowexecute
where year(b.dtstartdate) between 2009 and 2020
and month(b.dtstartdate)>=7
and ... -- other filters
```